# How do you create two tables within one excel sheet Using visual studio ETL?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, etl

I am creating an ETL on visual studio, and I want to export two different tables from my flow to the same excel sheet. So far I can only export the tables to different sheets within excel.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/merge-transformation

Comment: Using Merge or Merge Join (if you can) you should be able to combine them together to flow to 1 sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the Union all component.

SO you can use both sources and export them to your excel file.